# Strange Laravel problem, not with my code: production.ERROR: URI must be a string or UriInterface

Tags: laravel

We just deployed new code to our website today and now it's throwing errors, but the errors aren't coming from our code. What in the world could be the problem?

```
[2024-02-23 21:41:02] production.ERROR: URI must be a string or UriInterface {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): URI must be a string or UriInterface at /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php:461)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(161): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Utils::uriFor()
#1 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(189): GuzzleHttp\\Client->requestAsync()
#2 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(641): GuzzleHttp\\Client->request()
#3 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\{closure}()
#4 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#5 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(81): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#6 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#7 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(662): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#8 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(335): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#9 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(307): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->callAfterCallbacks()
#10 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(226): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->finish()
#11 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(192): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->run()
#12 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/View/Components/Task.php(37): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\{closure}()
#13 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/View/Components/Factory.php(58): Illuminate\\Console\\View\\Components\\Task->render()
#14 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(207): Illuminate\\Console\\View\\Components\\Factory->__call()
#15 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(131): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->runEvent()
#16 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->handle()
#17 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#18 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#19 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#20 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(662): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#21 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(211): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#22 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#23 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(181): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#24 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1096): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#25 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(324): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#26 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(175): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#27 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(201): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#28 /home/forge/example/releases/20240223210844/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#29 {main}
"}
```

Comment: which command did you run ? are you calling a https link with a non valid ssl certificate ?